# Wordpress functions load scripts by page template

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have the following code in my functions file, as I only want to load certain JS and CSS if this page template is being used pages. But for some reason it isn't loading, any help on what is wrong? My templates are within the directory page-templates in my theme, and the template is loading but not the files...

```
function slick_scripts() {
if(is_page_template('template_choose-your-door.php')){
wp_enqueue_style( 'slick-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slick.css', array(),     '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slick.min.js',      array(), '1.0.0', true ); 
}
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slick_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that:

1) The 2 files exist and the URLs you've enqueued are correct.

2) You have called wp_head() and wp_footer() in your theme code (that is where wp_enqueue hooks to).

Comment: This is all correct, however they aren't loading, any ideas? is my code incorrect?

Comment: You should remove the fifth parameter "true" from wp_enqueue_style(), as this parameter is related to the "media" attribute of the css link tag. Other than that everything in your code is correct, so you have to look at something else - either the files are missing, or you don't have wp_head() / wp_footer() in your template for some reason, or the page template name in the condition is not correct. Usually, wp_head() is called in header.php, and wp_footer() is called in footer.php, so make sure you have get_header() and get_footer() in your page template.

Answer (score 0):

If your templates are within the directory "page-templates" , your call to is_page_template() should be

```
is_page_template('page-templates/template_choose-your-door.php')
```

Reference:

[from the codex - under "Notes"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)

Comment: It was staring me in the face, I thought I had tried this, thanks for posting your answer.